# Error when returning callback which returns type matching interface

Tags: go

Example of error @ play.golang.org: http://play.golang.org/p/GRoqRHnTj6

The following code is returning a "prog.go:16: cannot use NewMyGame (type func() MyGame) as type func() Playable in return argument" even though the interface is completely empty.  Please find code attached below too, I'm completely stumped unfortunately and any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
package main

// Define an arbitrary game type
type MyGame struct{}

// Create a constructor function for arbitrary game type
func NewMyGame() MyGame {
    return MyGame{}
}

// Define an interface defining game types
type Playable interface{}

// In my app it will return a list of constructors matching interface
func Playables() func() Playable {
    return NewMyGame
}

func main() {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly as the error says,

```
cannot use NewMyGame (type func() MyGame) as type func() Playable
```

A simple fix would be

```
func Playables() func() Playable {
    return func() (Playable) {
        return NewMyGame()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the answer makes sense, and indeed works for me in my app.

You wouldn't happen to know why meeting interface requirements wouldn't be possible at the callback signature level, but works when you wrap the constructor call in another callback?

Comment: @beefsack It's because types in Go are pretty concrete. Search around for questions about slices of interfaces. It also matters because interfaces are basically a 2 pointer box, which changes the size of the return value.